# Some "converse" of mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The mean value theorem states that if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous over $[x_0,x]$, and differentiable over $(x_0,x)$, then there exists $x^*\in(x_0,x)$ s.t. $f'({x^*}) = \frac{{f(x) - f({x_0})}}{{x - {x_0}}}$.

Now suppose $f$ is differentiable over $[x_0,+\infty)$, for any $x^*>x_0$, can we always choose some $x>x^*$ s.t. $f'({x^*}) = \frac{{f(x) - f({x_0})}}{{x - {x_0}}}$?

Comment: What if $f=0$ on $[x_0,x^*]$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x>x_0?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:

For $f(x) = x^3$  we have $f'(0) = 0$, but for all $x_0 < x$ in $[-1,1]$ we have

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} = \frac{x^3 - x_0^3}{x-x_0} = x^2 + xx_0 + x_0^2 > 0.$$

In general, you need more restrictions for the converse to hold.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x):=\cos x$, and put $x_0=0$, $x^*={\pi\over2}$. Then there is no $x>x^*$ such that
$$f'(x^*)=-1={f(x)-f(0)\over x}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

If  $f$ is  strictly monotonic  and $f'(x^*)=0$ then $f'(x^*)=0\ne  (f(x)-f(x_0))/(x-x_0)$ for any $x\ne x_0$. For example if $f(x)=(x-x^*)^3.$